# Find out if a value is within a range with one if clause in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, string-length

What I'm doing now:

```
$length = strlen($string);
if( $length > 5 && $length < $10 )
```

In order to avoid double length measurement:

```
if( strlen($string) > 5 && strlen($string) < 10 )
```

**Is there a nicer way of doing this?** Something like:

```
if( 5 < strlen($string) < 10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *between* operator in PHP. You could do something like:

```
if (in_array($someVar, range($min, $max)))

if (in_array(strlen($string), range(6, 9))) // In your case 5 and 10 are not included
```

The way you are doing is nice and clean, and probably a bit faster than the in_array+range.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in PHP there is no guaranteed expression evaluation order: [see PHP language developer discussion here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61188). So, avoiding the temporary variable in your exapmle will by risky and depends on the PHP version, platform, etc.

To avoid double evaluation in an expression, you can build a string class and cache the length once it has been evaluated for later access.